# Coverage 0 Junit 5 spring boot tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, junit5

I have tests that jacoco is not scanning and including into the report. The coverage is  0, I read a lot posts but nothing works.
Below, my configuration:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'

id 'jacoco'
id 'java'
id 'eclipse'
id 'maven-publish'
id 'war'
id 'base'
id 'idea'}


dependencies {
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'*

}

jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
}
}



check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

In my test class I use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).

Comment: As stated in the documentation of this plugin (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_getting_started ), the `jacocoTestReport` does not explicitly  depends on `test` task. So maybe in your case, the jacoco task is executed before test? please try to create dependency `jacocoTestReport.dependsOn  test`, just to make sure.

Comment: Using ˋ@RunWithˋ means that it’s a JUnit 4 test. So maybe you’re not really running tests at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've reviewed and my problem is because my units tests are not executing. It is because my project is with org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1, and It doesn't scan org.junit.test annotation. Any idea?

Comment: You need junit-vintage-engine to run junit4 tests. You seem to explicitly exclude this dependency.

Remove the exclude, or port your tests to use  annotations from jupiter package.